# Invoking a C callback function with supplied variadic arguments gives strange result

Tags: c, callback, arguments, variadic

In the code below float or double parameters are not working, value is always wrong. ints and strings work as expected.

I'm about to give up on this construct and try something else unless someone can discover the problem.

```
typedef void(*varfunc)(...);
typedef void(*invokefunc)(int, ...);

varfunc func_table[2];

void register_func(int slot, varfunc cb)
{
    func_table[slot] = cb;
}

void invoke_func(int slot, void* a1, void* a2, void* a3, void* a4)
{
    func_table[slot](a1, a2, a3, a4);
}

void func_1(float a, int b)
{
    printf("%f %d", a, b);
}

void func_2(const char* c)
{
    printf("%s", c);
}


int main()
{
    register_func(0, (varfunc)func_1);
    register_func(1, (varfunc)func_2);

    ((invokefunc)invoke_func)(0, 1.23f, 456);
    ((invokefunc)invoke_func)(1, "hello world");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To me, this looks as if it shouldn't work at all. You must access the variadic arguments with the `va_...` macros from `<stdarg.h>`. (And that might be how you could perhaps implement your idea: make a `varfunc` take a `va_list` as argument. But I really don't see the benefit of such a design. Variadic functions mean that you lose type safety and if you mix up the slots, `func_2` will very likely crash.)

Comment: This works and I have seen similar constructions in public library's. Unfortunately va_list demands passing number of arguments and breaks the whole point with this idea. My opinion about type safety is that type safety have no part in C its up to the programmer to be type-safe and knowing the data.

Comment: Well, it works as you describe if I remove the `...` from the `varfunc` definition. By the way, you don't have to pass the number of arguments with a `va_list`. You must have at least one names parameter before the `...`, though, but that does not apply to a `va_list` argument.  And you do have an argument in the function that requires it, the slot id. [Here's](https://ideone.com/S7SZFw) how that could work. The floating-point number gets printed correctly.

Comment: Yes you right, that could work. But In that case i would need some kind of wrapper that unpacks the correct arguments and dispatches the callback. That is similar to what I have right now except that instead of va_list i'm using parameter structures for each type of function call. But I will definitely try something like you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a wrapper, but you must implement your callbacks in terms of a `va_list`, from which you have to "unpack" the values. (That's a bit like `shift`ing the a sub's arguments from `@_` in Perl 5.) Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, you specify the arguments to `invoke_func` as void pointers which may have different sizes than floats or ints, and as such, will cause undefined behavior when you pass them to `func_1`. I've modified `func_1` as follows:

```c
void func_1(float* a, int* b)
{
    printf("%f %d", *a, *b);
}
```

And now you can invoke it with:

```c
float a = 1.23f;
int b = 456;

((invokefunc)invoke_func)(0, &a, &b);
```

This runs successfully on my machine.

Comment: Yea that's right, thanks. But that makes it quite cumbersome to do function calls, no fun at all. I did a little bit different approach in a signal/slot system I'm currently working on where i basically use a dispatch function and cast a void function pointer to correct function by knowing the type of signal that was invoked. But it ment allot of patching and pointer casting.